# HP device manager can not save (Print color as gray) option

Tags: cups

[image]'

whenever I change this value to Off and reopen the application, it turns back to On,

this only happens with this specific option

I tried reinstalling hplip, but it did not solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
lpoptions -o HPPJLColorAsGray=off
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  A few notes on your answer to hopefully help in the future.  **(1)** It could be improved with additional supporting information, but I wouldn't recommend it in this case (see #3). You can find more information in [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) - *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."*  It might be helpful to review some highly upvoted answers as examples to follow

Comment: **(2)** Check out [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](/help/formatting) and the [Markdown help](/editing-help) for tips on making your future answers more readable.

Comment: **(3)** In this case, it doesn't matter much, because your answer just called attention to the face that the *question* that was originally asked isn't on-topic here, since it's not a *programming* question. As a result it was (correctly) closed and will probably be automatically deleted shortly. This is why the [help](/help/how-to-answer) recommends that you, *"Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which ... are not about programming"*.  We don't want you to waste your time! If you have programming expertise, look for good *programming* questions here to answer.

Comment: And if not, we have some other sites where your command-line expertise can be useful, including [Super User](//superuser.com), [Unix & Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com), and potentially [Ask Ubuntu](//askubuntu.com)

Comment: I know this is a lot to take in when you are brand new here, and there's no problem with that.  It's why I spend time trying to provide guidance in comments for new users. ;-)  Again, Welcome!